# findOneAndDelete Mongoose not working MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-redux

GoodDay Experts,

I've tried following code but it did not work, and it gives me null value.. maybe my routes are wrong but basically it works the way on other routes... and here is my backend for delete case: manage.js/actions

```
export const removeRecipient = (payload) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.delete(
      `${_config.MAT_URL}/api/1/customer/delete`,
      payload
    );
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_CUSTOMER,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { err },
    });
  }
};
```

and for my routes which is the mongoose query for findOneAndDelete, under customer.js :

```
   router.delete("/delete", (req, res) => {
  Customer.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, Customer) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.json({ msg: "customer deleted", deleted: Customer });
    } else {
      console.log("Error removing :" + err);
    }
  });
});
```

And for the front end im using "AiOutlineDelete" which was coded as :

```
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log('delete')
    removeRecipient(id)
  }

<a
  id={`delete-${rowIndex}`}
  className="anchor-action-delete"
  href="#foo"
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleDelete(row);
  }}>
```

thanks have a great day

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. `req.params.id` is meant for urls of the form `/delete/:id` which is obviously not your route, you should change it to `req.query.id` instead which matches query parameters in the url such as `/delete?id=123`.
2. The default type of `_id` is `ObjectId`, under the assumption you did not change this you need to cast your `req.query.id` which is type `string` to `ObjectId`.

It looks like you're using mongoose so here's mongoose syntax:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

router.delete("/delete", (req, res) => {
    Customer.findOneAndDelete({ _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.id) }, (err, Customer) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.json({ msg: "customer deleted", deleted: Customer });
        } else {
            console.log("Error removing :" + err);
        }
    });
});
```

For `nodejs` native Mongo package:

```
import {ObjectId} from "mongodb";
...

new ObjectId(req.query.id)
```

Comment: thanks for the reference... i try it on post man and redux dev tools.. the output under DELETE_CUSTOMER reducer : msg(pin):"customer deleted"
deleted(pin):null

Comment: How are you sending the id? using query params? if so use `req.query.id` instead.

Comment: when im sending query. for example like update router.post('/updateById')... findOneAndUpdate {_id} { $set: {name,email,organisation}} something like that

Comment: Did you change your code to be `req.query.id` instead of `req.params.id`?, I added a brief explanation to my answer.

Comment: Same output as well... It appears on log that the value is not getting an "_id(ObjectID)".. still in null..

Answer (score 0):

I dont see you sent the id to the backend but you are trying to retrieve it from req.params.id  try passing the id like "delete/:id" at the end of the link and specify this in the routes aswell.

if that doesnt fix try the below code this for routes

if nothing works check this, In the component you need to send the id(object id) but i see "row" what is the value of row? if the row value is not the id in the database then it wont delete. if this your issue try inspecting the code by keeping breakpoints or write a console.log() to check the value of "row" .

```js
    try {
        const removedProject = await Customer.remove({
            _id: req.params.id
        })
        res.json(removedProject)
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({
            message: err
        })
    }
```

Comment: DepricationWarning appears... Collection.remove is deprecated. Rather use deleteOne, deleteMany, ir bulkWrite

Comment: i've tried deleteOne and the output of the console : {n: 0, ok: 1, deletedCount: 0}
deletedCount: 0
n: 0
ok: 1

Comment: router.delete("/delete", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const removedCustomer = await Customer.deleteOne({
      _id: req.params.id
    })
    res.json(removedCustomer)
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({
      message: err
    })
  }
});

Comment: good sign that you got to see some response {n:0, ok:1.....} now lets check the value of id

Comment: once check the req.params.id value by writing console log after await statement like const removedProject = await Customer.deleteOne({
            _id: req.params.id
        }) console.log("id", req.params.id);

Comment: now compare the consolelog id value to the id in the database